# passing value to controller in codeigniter using ajax in jquery mobile

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pass latitude and longitude value to the index function in controller named `Add`. google chrome browser reveles correctly geolocation  but when I try to pass values in the controller using `$this->input->post('latitude)`, `$this->input->post('longitude')` these are blank. some idea ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          get_location();
      });

      function get_location()
      {
          if(navigator.geolocation)
          {
          register_coords(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition());
          }
      }

      function register_coords(position)
      {
          var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

          $.post("http://mysite:8888/add", {latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude});
      }

     console.log(position.coords);
  </script>

Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined
```

Comment: first, check that latittude and longitude actually consist of value by doing a simple javascript alert() on those two values. Then check in your httpd logging or if your controller has logging, see the ajax post call is really made?

Comment: well first of all the value are printed out correctly in alert javascript window.

Answer (score 0):

You switched the parameters and the function call. It should be:
  `register_coords(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition());`

**Edit:** entire answer

Comment: ok I added console.log(position.coords) at the end of my scripts and this is the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined. some idea?

Comment: nothing it doesn't work...another error appears: Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined
Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17

Comment: are you 100% sure navigator.geolocation has a value? do this inside get_location if `console.log(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition)` and tell me whats in the dev tools

Comment: This is the error I show: Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17
(anonymous function) when I execute console.log(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition())

Comment: Its hard to help you since I dont know what youre using, but did you load the other file that does the navigator() before loading this script? And are you sure getCurrentPosition() returns a value?

Comment: ok maybe I understood where I made mistakes but the code posted from me it is correct?

Comment: Ok so I'm working on my code and few minutes and I tell you the result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7970/discussion-between-eng-mazzy-and-mike)

Comment: My problem is: the script is passed in the header but I call $this->input->post('latitude') in the controller before the controller load  the header through $this->load->view('template'). is It an error right?